# Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior

Tags: android, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

In my App I have included this library https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View for bottom navigation and added recycler view scroll behavior

```
<com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:space_background_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:active_item_color="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        app:inactive_item_color="@color/colorWhite"
        app:centre_button_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:centre_button_icon="@drawable/ic_camera_white_24dp"
        app:inactive_centre_button_icon_color="@color/colorWhite"
     app:layout_behavior="com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior" />
```

I have mutidexenabled in gradle file. There is no progaurd rule added for the library. They didnt mention one to include.
Now this worked fine in debug mode. In release mode this fails with below error

```
Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #40: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior (SourceFile:628)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams. (SourceFile:2795)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams (SourceFile:1703)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams (SourceFile:112)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:860)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:377)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (SourceFile:287)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (SourceFile:139)
com.example.MainActivity.onCreate (SourceFile:77)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6687)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1140)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2631)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2743)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1490)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6165)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:888)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:778)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dev-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dev-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.dev-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior (SourceFile:621)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams. (SourceFile:2795)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams (SourceFile:1703)
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams (SourceFile:112)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:860)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:377)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (SourceFile:287)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (SourceFile:139)
arrow_right
com.example.MainActivity.onCreate (SourceFile:77)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6687)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1140)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2631)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2743)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1490)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6165)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:888)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: i have same problem if you are get the solution please mention it.

Comment: I have got the solution just remove app:layout_behavior="com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior"  line or mention the progaurd behavior files by -keep

Answer (score 1):

**I have got the Solution :-**

```
package com.luseen.spacenavigation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

    /**
     * Created by Chatikyan on 13.10.2016.
     */
    public class SpaceNavigationViewBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

        public SpaceNavigationViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super();
        }

        public SpaceNavigationViewBehavior() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, View dependency) {
            return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, final V child, View dependency) {
            float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
            child.setTranslationY(translationY);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, V child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
            // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
            return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                    || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final V child,
                                   final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed,
                                   final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {
            super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
            if (dyConsumed > 0) {
                Utils.makeTranslationYAnimation(child, child.getHeight());
            } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
                Utils.makeTranslationYAnimation(child, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```